# Pillow fight on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, games-toys

Is it allowed to have a pillow fight on shabbat for fun, or is it like [running which is forbidden](http://halachayomit.co.il/EnglishDefault.asp?HalachaID=2428)?

Comment: Running is forbidden?

Comment: Hi ray. Where are you getting the idea that running is forbidden? Also, why would pillow-fighting be like running? I can imagine some potential issues with pillow-fighting on Shabbos, but none of them have to do with running.

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe he meant playing with ball, which is also forbidden...Or maybe not....

Comment: I'm voting to close as "unclear what you're asking" in the mean time.

Comment: gemora says running is forbidden http://halachayomit.co.il/EnglishDefault.asp?HalachaID=2428

Comment: By running he probably means exercise.

Comment: @ray how odd. I thought running to shul was a mitzva on shabbat

Comment: who's talking about running to shul? running to do a mitzva is an exception as you probably know

Comment: @ray Even if the gemara says that running is forbidden, what is your justification for comparing pillow-fighting to running? Your link suggests that there is not much of a problem about running when it is for pleasure.

Comment: Are you speaking of children or adults/

Comment: adults, i.e. over barmitzva

Comment: Is it an exception or was it never included?

Comment: Ray, @DoubleAA is just trying to get you to clarify (in the question) what you mean.

Comment: ...mostly to encourage you to not use absolute statements to represent non-absolute propositions.

Comment: Wouldn't use of a feather pillow be a problem as the feathers might poke a hole (tearing?) and they fly in the air ("scattering"?)

Answer (score 3):

Even running, if one takes pleasure in running, like young men who enjoy running, it is permitted (Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 301, 2), so certainly a pillow fight which is done for fun is permitted. In addition, one of the explanations for the prohibition of running is that appears as though one is running to work (see Mishna Berurah 301, 1), and this certainly does not apply to a pillow fight.

Comment: do you have a source that running for pleasure is permitted? is this only for casual low distance running or even one which could be considered light exercise.

Comment: @ray The link inserted by msh210 states that running for pleasure is OK.

Comment: I added the sources. As long as one is enjoying the running, it is permitted.